# Subversion large repos import/checkout

Tags: svn, repository, commit, svn-checkout

My normal work flow to create a new repository with subversion is to create a new repos, do a checkout of the repos root, create my branches tags and trunk folders and place in the trunk my initial files. Then I do a commit of this "initial import", delete the checked out repos from my hard drive and do a checkout of the trunk. Then I can start working.

However, when dealing with a large import, think hundreds of megs, and off-site version control hosting (http based) this initial import can take quite a while to commit. What's worse, after committing I need to checkout this massive trunk all over again.

Is there a way with subversion to use the local copy of the trunk without doing a checkout all over again of data that is already there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is - it's called an "in-place import", and it's covered in the Subversion FAQ here:

http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#in-place-import

What you're really doing is creating a new empty project in the repository, checking out the empty project your local folder - which turns your folder into a working copy - and then adding all your (existing) files to that 'empty' project, so they're added to the repository when you do an svn commit.

Answer (score 4):

I agree on  the  "in-place import" procedure and also using a script for TTB-structure(upvoted both).

Just a small hint:

You should not import a **huge** (ten of thousands) number of files in a single commit, if you use http(s), as the time for displaying the version history *scales by the number of added entries*. The reason for this behaviour is that apache has to authenticate all added paths agains the svnaccess file(of course, only if you enabled path-based authorization). This can render your repository unusable, as all files will have to wait on a svn log for this big rev.

You should divide huge imports on directory levels

Comment: Sometimes you get ownership of a project that has existed for some time but has never been under version control. Projects that use video resource can grow quite large.

Comment: that is no problem, only the number of files countsk, not their size. And this is only applicable to apache, not svn server itself

Answer (score 2):

I usually use "svn mkdir" to create the trunk/tags/branches directly on the server immediately after creating the repository. Then I can check out the empty trunk, move my initial files into that directory, add and commit them, and start working.

Comment: Personally I don't like to do this because it creates a bunch of unnecessary revisions in my repository. I prefer to check out the root, create the structure I need and do a single commit of the new structure.

Comment: Luke: Arguably, your source control repository will eventually contain mostly "unnecessary revisions", so I'm not sure how one extra commit will make a difference. (You can make all three directories at once with "svn mkdir dir1 dir2 dir3 -m whatever")

Answer (score 2):

svn checkout --force lets you checkout a  workingcopy 'over' an existing path. It keeps your old files and adds files that are only in your repository.

For creating your repository: You can perform multiple mkdir commands to a repository in a single commit using the 'svnmucc' command that is available in most Subversion distributions (e.g. [SlikSVN](http://sliksvn.com/en/download/)).

Type svnmucc without arguments for some help.

Answer (score 1):

If you've checked out a single folder, copied your files into it, run `svn add` and `svn commit`;  you shouldn't need to delete the files and re-checkout.

Use the files in place: once they've been committed as you describe, they're ready to be worked on.